# Dialog box for Panel only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, modal-dialog, panel

I know that it may be sound stupid but it is a real requirement for my project . I have a panel inside a form and this panel is used only for opening and closing subsequent forms. Now I have a show a dialogbox asking for yes or no inside a panel but when a form is already opened inside that panel . This is the first problem . Another is I want that the dialog box should only halt the operation inside the panel , not the form containing the panel.  Is there a way to get this.  Please share some code for this .

Answer (score 0):

I probably understand your first requirement. Open other Forms in the panel. If there is already a Form in the panel, a prompt box will pop up asking whether to continue.

code show as below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form2 form2;

    Form3 form3;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(form2 == null&&form3 == null)
        {
            CheckPanel();
        }
        else
        {
            TipBox();
        }

    }

    public void CheckPanel()
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {

            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.TopLevel = false;
            form2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            form2.Parent = panel1;
            if (form3 != null)
            {
                form3.Hide();
            }
            form2.Show();

        }

        else if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            form3 = new Form3();
            form3.TopLevel = false;
            form3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            form3.Parent = panel1;
            if (form2 != null)
            {
                form2.Hide();
            }
            form3.Show();
        }
    }

    public void TipBox()
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to continue?", "Tip", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result.Equals(DialogResult.Yes))
        {
            CheckPanel();
            
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The demonstration is as follows:

[image]

Please tell me if I understand it incorrectly. I don't understand your second question very well. Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: https://github.com/Shaifalijain31/copyprojectshaifalijain
there is a main form as mainmaster . it has panel named Mainmasterpanel . this panel is used to open all the forms inside it . now when application starts , A form named TDlloading_error opens inside this mainmasterpanel . if the user presses escape a new form named as formbackground is shown  ( with some opacity and transparency ) and upon it a form named as MainExitForm opens as dialogbox  as showdialog() . upto here all good .

Comment: the problem is when this MainExitForm (dialog box ) loads,As we know that showdialog halts the execution of all forms until they are closed  i just want that it should block the execution of panel and its forms only .

Comment: I ran your project as you described and when I try and hold "Esc" the whole screen goes dark but no new page pops up

Comment: pls find the project on https://github.com/Ankitgoel2009/Tallyincsharp

Comment: pls find the project on the above link